# Switchable proxy ip setup for Nginx and Gunicorn with Django

Tags: django, nginx, ip, gunicorn

I have `VDS` with `debian` and `nginx`, `gunicorn`,`django` installation.
And many domains, that are resolving to ip.

I'm planning to buy additional ip from my provider.

My goal is: easy switch ip for current domain.

Surely i can do it 1 way: use dns hosting, and change ip from A records when it need.
But there are another way: proxying traffic somehow. I have nginx configuration:

```
...
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
    server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com;
...
```

How i can setup server, so i'll can store and manage proxying domain ip form database in django?